# The same vlookup/match works by itself but broken with arrayformula (for certain type of the lookup value)

Tags: google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

The first spreadsheet "Book" contains input of range and row I want to fetch data from the second sheet "Bell". There is one type of the lookup values which doesn't show anything in the arrayformula.

I tried the individual functions of both vlookup and match, they worked fine. But once I put them into the arrayformula, it said

```
Did not find value '......' in VLOOKUP/MATCH evaluation.
```

Here are sample of the code as standalone

```
=vlookup(F1,indirect("Bell!"&J1,TRUE),2,FALSE)
```

And here is when I place it into an arrayformula

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(F2:F,indirect("Bell!"&J2:J,TRUE),2,FALSE))
```

The column J is the A1 notation of the range I want the vlookup to search.

The only problem is there is one type of value that cannot be evaluated, specifically it is either "2-10/12" or "2-11". I suspected that maybe it is because the these 2 values are not number. (The other possible lookup values are number 1 to 8.).

How fix there issue? I tried to format the lookup value Book!F:F and all the possible columns like Bell!J:J as "Plain text", it doesn't work. I tried TO_TEXT, also doesn't work.

Comment: `INDIRECT` does not work as one might expect inside `ARRAYFORMULA`. It just evaluates once. Your formula is equivalent to `=arrayformula(vlookup(F2:F,indirect("Bell!"&J2,TRUE),2,FALSE))`

Comment: Thank you, Kishkin. How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: Depends on you problem and on what you have. An example sheet might be helpful.